# Word request for an academic paper/article that is 'hidden', 'difficult to find'

Tags: single-word-requests

I have come across an article that seems to have been published in a book that is only available online with restricted access, and the paper is not reproduced e.g. on the arXiv. I am writing on a related topic, and wanted to refer to this paper in a sentence: "the [hidden/elusive/difficult to find/ etc] paper ... by ...". Clearly though, those words aren't really applicable here.

Comment: I might be inclined to use "inaccessible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*obscure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscure) might work; it combines feelings of "concealment", "hard to get to" and "relatively unknown".

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/75238/70594) is an example of its use on one of our sister sites, MathOverflow:

> #### How to locate an obscure paper?
>
> A colleague asked me to locate the following paper on the web:
>
> Kovalenko, I.N.: On the reconstruction of an additive type of distribution based upon a sequence of independent trials.
>   Memoirs of the All-Union Conference on Probability Theory and Mathematical Statistics, Erevan 1958.
>
> After a few failed attempts, I asked myself, how would I go about locating this paper in the REAL (not virual) world? What library stocks proceedings of the All-Union Conference... in Erevan, from 1958?

Comment: Except that "obscure" would most commonly be taken to mean "To abstruse to read."

Comment: I agree with the commentor above, but I think if I use 'obscure' in the right context I can avoid that implication. It seems like the best word choice here.